# protected access when using objects

Tags: java, object, member, protected

I understand that protected access means that one can access the member within the package and any subclass, regardless of the package. What I find hard to understand is that, in a subclass, when I create an object of the class which has the protected member, I get a "not visible" error?
This is demonstrated by the following code (which is an expanded version based on an answer by YiFan Wu). Note that I have the same lines of code inside and outside of the package. Thus I have two questions:

1. Why does using the object change everything?
2. This object access difference does not happen within the package i.e. see test() in class A1.

   ```
   package a;
   public class A{
       protected int a;
   }
   class A1{
       public void test(){
           A ref = new A();
           ref.a=8;    // no issue
       }
   }

   package b;
   public class B extends A{
   }

   package c;
   public class C extends B｛
       public void accessField(){
           a = 2;   //That works.


           A ref = new A();
           ref.a=8;   // not visible!!
       }
   ```

   }

Any help much appreciated...

Thanks,
Sean.

Answer (score 2):

Because `C` is in another package, and you're creating an `A`, *not* a subclass of `A`.

Flip the question on its head: why *should* it be visible? You already know the packaging rules, and you already know the field access rules.

Comment: In fact this is compiler laziness: if you did `C ref = new C();` you would have access to `ref` (I guess). Many criticize just that.

Comment: Hi Dave, that first line really explains it. My confusion arose because I expected to be able to access a protected member once inside a subclass (regardless of package). However, as you explained, once inside a different package, only the subclasses have access and thus I need to create an object of the subclass (or be inside a method of the subclass itself)... Many thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 1):

In the last case you're making a new instance of an A object.  This is completely different from using an instance of the subclass to access its parent class's members.

**When you create a subclass, it creates a parent class first.  The only subclass that has access to protected members in the parent instance is that subclass that the parent class was created with.**